# Db2 convert rows to columns

Tags: db2, db2-400

I need the below results ..

```
Table :

Order postcode qnty
123    2234        1
```

Expected result:

```
Order          123
Postcode       2234
Qnty           1
```

SQL server:

```
Select pvt.element_name
      ,pvt.element_value(select order.postcode
                         from table name)up
unpivot (element_value for element_name in(order,postcode) as Pvt
```

How to achieve this in db2?

Answer (score 1):

Db2 for IBM i doesn't have a built-in unpviot function..  AFAIK, it's not available on any Db2 platofrm...unless it's been added recently.

The straight forward method

```
select 'ORDER' as key, order as value 
from mytable
UNION ALL
select 'POSTCODE', postcode
from mytable
UNION ALL
select 'QNTY', char(qnty)
from mytable;
```

A better performing method is to do a cross join between the source table and a correlated VALUES of as many rows as columns that need to be unpivoted.

```
select 
   Key, value
from mytable T,
      lateral (values ('ORDER', t.order)
                      , ('POSTCODE', t.postcode) 
                      , ('QNQTY', varchar(t.qnty))
                      ) as unpivot(key, value);
```

However, you'll need to know ahead of time what the values you're unpivoting on.

If you don't know the values, there are some ways to unpivot with the XMLTABLE (possibly JSON_TABLE) that might work.  I've never used them, and I'm out of time to spend answering this question.  You can find some examples via google.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a stored procedure for LUW that rotate a table:
https://github.com/angoca/db2tools/blob/master/pivot.sql

You just need to call the stored procedure by passing the tablename as parameter, and it will return a cursor with the headers of the column in the first column.