# Converting table data to pie-chart data

Tags: db2, birt

Need to plot data extracted for table into a pie-chart.

I am selecting data from a table to count tickets with different scenarios. I am able to simply select data to be plotted in excel.
But I need to select the same data in such a way that It can be plotted in pie-chart also.

```
SELECT Sum(CASE
             WHEN Date(reportdate) < Date(current timestamp)
                  AND ( status NOT IN (SELECT value
                                       FROM   synonymdomain
                                       WHERE  maxvalue IN ( 'RESOLVED', 'CLOSED'
                                                            ,
                                                            'REJECTED' )
                                              AND domainid IN ( 'INCIDENTSTATUS'
                                                              )) )
                  AND incident.ir IS NOT NULL THEN 1
           end)     AS IMs_Balance_Carry_Forward,
       ( Sum(CASE
               WHEN Date(reportdate) = Date(current timestamp)
                    AND ( status NOT IN (SELECT value
                                         FROM   synonymdomain
                                         WHERE  maxvalue IN (
                                                'RESOLVED', 'CLOSED',
                                                'REJECTED' )
                                                AND domainid IN (
                                                    'INCIDENTSTATUS' )) )
                    AND ( incident.ir IS NOT NULL ) THEN 1
             end) ) AS IM_Added_During_the_day,
       from         INCIDENT
```

Current Result:

```
 IMS_BALANCE_CARRY_FORWARD        IM_ADDED_DURING_THE_DAY

         120                            8
```

Required Result"

```
Column1                            Column2

 IMS_BALANCE_CARRY_FORWARD            120
 IM_ADDED_DURING_THE_DAY               8
```

Answer (score 0):

You want an unpivot capability, this has been answered here before. [previous question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57493781/db2-convert-rows-to-columns)